# show notify after save data using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I tried to want to display a notification when to save data and display it in the view , but do not run I use the notify.js . if anyone could help me?

This my control save

```
function save() {
    $data = array(                      
                'idsupplier' => $this->input->post('idsupplier'),
                'namasupplier' => $this->input->post('namasupplier'),
                'alamat' => $this->input->post('alamat'),
                'telp' => $this->input->post('telp'),
                'fax' => $this->input->post('fax'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'web' => $this->input->post('web'),
                'kontak1' => $this->input->post('kontak1'),
                'hp1' => $this->input->post('hp1'),                     
                'email1' => $this->input->post('email1'),
                'kontak2' => $this->input->post('kontak2'),
                'hp2' => $this->input->post('hp2'),                     
                'email2' => $this->input->post('email2'));  
    $this->mcrud->addsupplier($data);   
    echo '<script>Notify("Alat Baru Berhasil Ditambahkan Ke Database ", null, null, type);</script>';

    redirect('instrument/detailsupplier');
```

This my view

```
                <style>
                #notifications {
                    cursor: pointer;
                    position: fixed;
                    right: 0px;
                    z-index: 9999;
                    bottom: 0px;
                    margin-bottom: 22px;
                    margin-right: 15px;
                    max-width: 300px;   
                }
                </style>
     <div id="notifications"></div>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
                Notify("Alat Baru Berhasil Ditambahkan Ke Database ", null, null, type);

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be just as easier to use [session flash data](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata)

```
function save() {
    $data = array(                      
        'idsupplier' => $this->input->post('idsupplier'),
        'namasupplier' => $this->input->post('namasupplier'),
        'alamat' => $this->input->post('alamat'),
        'telp' => $this->input->post('telp'),
        'fax' => $this->input->post('fax'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'web' => $this->input->post('web'),
        'kontak1' => $this->input->post('kontak1'),
        'hp1' => $this->input->post('hp1'),                     
        'email1' => $this->input->post('email1'),
        'kontak2' => $this->input->post('kontak2'),
        'hp2' => $this->input->post('hp2'),                     
        'email2' => $this->input->post('email2')); 
    );

}

$this->mcrud->addsupplier($data);  

$this->session->set_flashdata('something', 'Alat Baru Berhasil Ditambahkan Ke Database');

// Codeigniter set flash data will only work when your redirecting

redirect('instrument/detailsupplier');

}
```

Then on your view

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('something')) {?>

    <div id="notifications"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('something');</div>

<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a flash message on success and check flash message and fire Notify. See below code.

```
function save() {
    $data = array(                      
                'idsupplier' => $this->input->post('idsupplier'),
                'namasupplier' => $this->input->post('namasupplier'),
                'alamat' => $this->input->post('alamat'),
                'telp' => $this->input->post('telp'),
                'fax' => $this->input->post('fax'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'web' => $this->input->post('web'),
                'kontak1' => $this->input->post('kontak1'),
                'hp1' => $this->input->post('hp1'),                     
                'email1' => $this->input->post('email1'),
                'kontak2' => $this->input->post('kontak2'),
                'hp2' => $this->input->post('hp2'),                     
                'email2' => $this->input->post('email2'));  
    $this->mcrud->addsupplier($data);   
    //set flash message
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Alat Baru Berhasil Ditambahkan Ke Database');

    redirect('instrument/detailsupplier');
```

**On your View**

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('msg')) {?>
     <script>
      Notify(<?=$this->session->flashdata('msg')?>, null, null, type);
     </script>
<?php } ?>
```